# JavaScript Object and methods but getName is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, object, member-functions

I'm learning JavaScript and write a simple demo, but failed. Could you help me out why `getName` is not a function? Thanks.

```js
var newPerson = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  getName: return function() {
    return this.name;
  }  
};  
   
var personOne = newPerson("Diego");  
var personTwo = newPerson("Gangelo");  
console.log(personOne.getName()); // prints Diego  
console.log(personTwo.getName()); // prints Gangelo
```

Comment: Could you run it ? Did you find any error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to return an object with some exposed methods. In that case, this is what I would have done.

```js
var newPerson = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    var self = this; 

    return {
        getName: function () {
            return self.name
        }
    }
}

var personOne = new newPerson("Diego");  
var personTwo = new newPerson("Gangelo");  
console.log(personOne.getName()); // prints Diego  
console.log(personTwo.getName()); // prints Gangelo
```

Edit: thanks to Pootie

Alternatively you could just do this.

```js
    var newPerson = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        
        this.getName = function () {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    var personOne = new newPerson("Diego");  
    var personTwo = new newPerson("Gangelo");  
    console.log(personOne.getName()); // prints Diego  
    console.log(personTwo.getName()); // prints Gangelo
```

Next time, use console.log() instead of document.write() because it's easier to debug.

Comment: this is wrong. first, your method is static, you're just overwriting "this.name" each time you call newPerson. you need to call `new` to make it a "class" and you need to reference "this" when returning the name or else youre just returning whatever you passed into the fnuction. see: https://jsfiddle.net/v0bko3ug/1/

Comment: ok, well, after the edit looksbetter but you're stll returning whatever "name" happens to be in you first example instead of the property of the object

Comment: @PootieTang Can you explain that? Why is what I have done wrong?

Comment: @pzp Hmm, I did that first but it was undefined. I think I will use Pooties jsfiddle example

Comment: if you remove the `this.name = name;` from the first example it still works, because you're not returning the name property of the object. the reason it still returns the name is because the name varibale you passed is still in the scope of the getName function.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it like this

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};
var personOne = new Person("Diego");
var personTwo = new Person("Gangelo");
document.write(personOne.getName()); // prints Diego  
document.write(personTwo.getName()); // prints Gangelo
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if we're [introducing Object-Oriented Programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript), I might as well show you how JavaScript does it best:

```js
// The ECMAScript 5 way

function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function getName() {
  return this.name;
};

var personOne = new Person("Diego");
var personTwo = new Person("Gangelo");

console.log(personOne.getName());
console.log(personTwo.getName());
```

This next one uses [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and is part of the new JavaScript standard.

**Note** this syntax is still in the "experimental stage" as far as browser implementation goes, and may not work on your browser.

```js
// The ECMAScript 6 way

class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

let personOne = new Person("Diego");
let personTwo = new Person("Gangelo");

console.log(personOne.getName());
console.log(personTwo.getName());
```

Comment: `let` is not a js6 substitute for `var`, they do entirely different things. there;s no reason to use let here.

Comment: @PootieTang I am aware of their differences, and in the spirit of giving a full ES6 answer, I opted to forgo their differences in order to show the important part. In fact, there's no reason _not_ to use them here.

Comment: there not being a reason not to is not a reason. however there is a reason not to... let should never be used unless there is an explicit reason **to** use it. but here's the reason why you shouldn't use it. https://jsfiddle.net/xnujfzf1/  ...don't add irrelevant code *just* because it's js6..

Comment: @PootieTang The whole reason `let` exists is so that people don't try to propagate that flawed scoping design in the first place, but I didn't come here to have a philosophical debate about a simple construct that has nothing to do with the original question, so unless you have something to contribute that is _relevant to the question_ then please stop complaining about my perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @PootieTang I might as well point out that your demonstration doesn't work, and not even for the reason you intended. Misplaced `else` keyword first and foremost, and the fact that you run `console.log(personOne.getName())` even if the `else` section is executed, is a logical error completely unrelated to the choice between `let` and `var`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9zfhnzk/) is a much more compelling argument for why `let` is considerably better than `var`. Check the console and see what the problem is for yourself.

Comment: my example breaks because of the let, the object doesn't exist outside of the conditional in a let. it has nothing to do with the else. and yes, in a loop is exactly the type of scoping let is good for, but there's no loop. it's sad that i have to explain this i dont get why youre being so stubborn about something so asinine/..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114363/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-pootie-tang).

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you liked my example I thought I'd post my personal preference. No need to return an object like the other examples do since the function itself is an object. Everything in JS is an object as a matter of fact.

See this fork of the other answer: https://jsfiddle.net/6xpgjh94/

```
var newPerson = function (name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.getName = function(){
        return self.name
    };
}

var personOne = new newPerson("Diego");  
var personTwo = new newPerson("Gangelo");  
console.log(personOne.getName()); // prints Diego  
console.log(personTwo.getName()); // prints Gangelo
```